# How to write php extension that depends on other extension?

Tags: php, php-extension

I plan to write a PHP Query extension that will depends on the `pdo_mysql` extension.

My question is: how to instance php class that from other extension and call function that from other extension?

How do I warn the user to download the other extension before compiling my extension.

Are there any documents talking about this?

Comment: what are you asking actually , m in kind of conundrum

Answer (score 0):

A concrete dependency such as you describe comes with a lot of problems, and I'd advise you to abstract away the dependency via an interface or callback. But if you are dead set on the idea...

`zend_lookup_class` will get you a class entry by string.

`object_init_ex` will instantiate an object given a class entry.

That should be enough to get you going.